# Sum of series $1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1\times3}{4\times8}+\frac{1\times3\times5}{4\times8 \times12}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

> Sum of series :
>   $$1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1\times3}{4\times8}+\frac{1\times3\times5}{4\times8 \times12}+\cdots$$

---

$n$-th term of series is 
$$a_{n} =\frac{1\times3 \times5\times\cdots \times(2n-1)}{4\times8\times12\times \cdots  \times4n} = \prod^{n}_{k=1}{2k-1\over4k}$$

I can not go further,

Comment: Is the answer $\sqrt{2} $

Comment: @ArchisWelankar:  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+((2n)!)%2F8%5En%2F(n!)%5E2) says so  I would look to see the series as a Taylor series for a trig function, but haven't found it.

Comment: @Ross Millikan can you please check it again as my answer matches with answer below

Comment: @ArchisWelankar:  Why check again?  I agreed with you, just did not know how to derive it.  I got to line $(2)$ of the answer below.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Got the point and the error. I preserved everything original, so OP does not need to know product symbol. Also posting this type of problem and not knowing product symbol is rare. I think he does not know the Latex command for the symbol.

Comment: @Ross millikan i saw it as summation of infinite series of $(1-x)^n $ where n is obviously not a positive integer and then got it as series for $\frac {1}{(0.5)^{0.5}} $

Comment: @MarkusScheuer I got the error $a_{n} = 1+\prod^{n}_{k=1}{\left(2k-1\over4\color{red}{k}\right)}$ but i can't edit it because i need to edit minimum 6 character. Perhaps you can edit, as you have 30k reputation.

Comment: @A---B: Good observation. I've corrected it together with some other minor issues. Regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note, the general term $a_n, n\geq 1$ is
\begin{align*}
a_n=\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1)}{4\cdot8\cdot 12\cdots (4n)}
=\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1)}{(1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n)\cdot 4^n}
=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!}\cdot \frac{1}{4^n}\\
\end{align*}

with $$(2n-1)!!=(2n-1)\cdot(2n-3)\cdots 5\cdot 3\cdot 1$$ *[double factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)*.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!}\cdot\frac{1}{4^n}
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n)!}{n!(2n)!!}\cdot\frac{1}{4^n}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!2^n}\cdot\frac{1}{4^n}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{8^n}\tag{3}\\
> &=\left.\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\right|_{z=\frac{1}{8}}\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}}}\\
> &=\sqrt{2}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply $(2n)!=(2n)!!\cdot (2n-1)!!$.
- In (2) we use $(2n)!!=n!2^n$.
- In (3) we use $\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$.
- In (4) we use the generating function of the *[central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)*.

> **Add-on [2017-03-12]** according to a comment from @navinstudent.
>
> Using the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}&=(1-4z)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}(-4z)^n\qquad\qquad |z|<\frac{1}{4}
> \end{align*}
>   Since 
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}&=\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}-1\right)\cdots\left(-\frac{1}{2}-n+1\right)}{n!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n!}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\cdots\left(-\frac{2n-1}{2}\right)\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}\cdot(2n-1)!!
> =\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{(2n)!!}
> =\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}
> \end{align*}
>   we get $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}(-4z)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}z^n$$ and step (4) follows.

Comment: If I may add, for $k>2$, then  $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{(2^k)^n}=\sqrt{\frac{2^{k-2}}{2^{k-2}-1}}$$ where the OP's was just the case $k=3$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Interesting! Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Can you please provide a prove of generating function you used in point 4

Comment: @navinstudent: Explanation added.

Comment: @navinstudent: You're welcome! :-)